# C# Printing - When is data sent to printer?

Tags: c#, printing

I am building a windows form app to print documents in a very specific way... the application has to print page by page and stop each time a page is printed to ask for user parameters that will be used to print the next page.

As of right now I have been able to do the printing using a class of my own that derives from System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument and have overriden the OnBeginPrint, OnQueryPageSettings and OnPrintPage methods... my application stops each time a page is to be procesed and the user is able to set parameters and press the "OK" key to continue... I have coded this process in the OnPrintPage method but the thing is that the class finishes the complition of the whole document before is sent to the the printer... and, as I described above, I need my class to print a page, then stop and ask for user input, then print the second page and soo on until the entire document is printed.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to proceed!?!?, I have been looking on the Internet but have not found anything on how to handle such a strange case...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Consider printing separate documents instead of one document with multiple pages.

Comment: Why can you not ask for all parameters before starting to print?

Comment: It would also be handy if posted the code that you are using... I don't think the mind-readers come on during this hour.

Comment: Dour High Arch, sometimes the person printing has to turn the page over (if printer can do this automatiaclly) each time a page is printed

Comment: Bas, I had considered this option already but since I am a newbe on C# I wanted to be sure this could not be done using the PrintDocument namespace...

Answer (score 0):

The `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument` namespace only provides a mechanism for getting jobs into the print spooler.  Physical printing and scheduling is handled by the Windows Print Spooler.  What goes on under the hood of that is a whole world of drivers, queues, networked, virtual and other printer-related witchcraft.

You may want to look into the [Print Spooler API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff686807(v=vs.85).aspx), if you want to force print jobs through to the printer programmatically.

Comment: Hello Mike, considering what you are saying on your post I think the easies/faster solution would be to manage each page as a separated document as Bas suggest in his comment above...

Comment: does anybody knows where I can get tutorial on the Print Spooler API, or at least some examples!

Comment: @dragonov7 Yes, treating each page as a seperate document is probably the best approach.  I suspect that it's rather unusual for people to use the print spooler API.  I've only encountered it in passing, whilst working with non-standard printing devices, and don't know much more than that it exists.